# how to set onChange handler to change the language in react i18next

Tags: reactjs, i18next

-the select form that allow the user to change the language don't work with onclick how can I use onChange handler

- am using react i18next.

*keep in mind that am not getting any errors or warnings.
this is my code

```
import i18n from 'i18next';

export default function Footer() {
const languages = [
    {
      code: "fr",
      name: "francais",
      countryCode:"fr"
    },
    {
      code: "en",
      name: "english",
      countryCode:"gb"
    },
    {
      code: "ar",
      name: "العربية",
      countryCode:"sa"
    }
  ]


return <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example" >
{languages.map(({code,name, countryCode})=>{
  return(
    <option key={countryCode} onClick={()=> i18n.changeLanguage(code)}>{name}</option>
  )
})}
</Form.Select>
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, maybe on codesandbox or similar?

Comment: here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/react-code-works-on-mozilla-but-but-dont-on-chrome-ywtq5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onChange handler to change the language needs to be set on the Form.Select component, like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-code-works-on-mozilla-but-but-dont-on-chrome-forked-1lkvw?file=/src/Footer.js:579-657

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { Container, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Footer() {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  const languages = [
    {
      code: "fr",
      name: "francais",
      countryCode: "fr"
    },
    {
      code: "en",
      name: "english",
      countryCode: "gb"
    },
    {
      code: "ar",
      name: "العربية",
      countryCode: "sa"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="section footer">
      <Container>
        <Form.Select
          defaultValue={i18n.resolvedLanguage}
          onChange={e => {
            i18n.changeLanguage(e.target.value);
          }}
        >
          {languages.map(({ code, name, countryCode }) => {
            return (
              <option
                key={countryCode}
                value={code}
              >
                {name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </Form.Select>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you so much it works. but I still cant understand why it didn't work when I used click event on option tags??

Comment: because the option tag has no onClick